# Return fields one level up from subdocument query mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to return a field one level up in my subdocument query. My schema is:

```
profile:{  
    contacts:[{
        first_name:'Tom',
        last_name:'Smith',
        shared:[{
              owner_id:'something',
              other_data:'something'
        }]
    },
    {
        //.... more contacts
    }]
}
```

if I write a query to get a particular contact by matching something in the 'shared' subdocument, I have access to the fields in the subdocument.

My problem is I want to search for contacts based on an owner_id in the shared subdocument, but I want to return the 'first_name' and 'last_name' one level up.

To query the subdocument I would do the following:

```
db.profile.find({'contacts.shared':{ower_id:'something},{'first_name':1, 'last_name':1}})
```

Does not return the fields in the parent.

How do you move up a level to get those fields?

Comment: Is "profile" a field's name in your document?

Comment: Profile is the document

Comment: If "profile" is not a field's name then you should remove remove it from your post, also consider to show us the expected result.

Comment: Why would I remove it from the post when it is the document name? The desired result is described in my original post. I want to return the first and last name of the contacts where the ownder_id matches.

Comment: As you can see in the answer given to you, "profile" there is  misleading. That being said, your description of the expected output is not clear. If you really need the answer then you should consider to update your question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What Vignesh provided actually did work when removing "profile" from the unwind. Now I understand that the $unwind is uses for arrays. So thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
db.people.aggregate([
{$unwind:'$profile.contacts'},
{$unwind:'$profile.contacts.shared'},
{$match:{
    'profile.contacts.shared.owner_id':"1"}
},{
    $group:{
        _id:null,
        fname:{$first:"$profile.contacts.first_name"},
        lname:{$first:"$profile.contacts.last_name"}
    }
}
  ])
```

Comment: Hi Vignesh, thanks for turning me on to those modifiers, but your code snippet didn't work. It's actually db.profile.